# Java command prompt compile error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, command-prompt, javac

I started learning Java lately, and trying to make my first program based on book which is the "Hello World" program. 
After writing the script on notepad, i try to compile it on the command prompt and then this notice appeared.

first I type: javac javaCode.java

then there a notice said:

```
    javaCode.java:2: error: <identifier> expected
    public class static void main(string[] args) {
                ^
    javaCode.java:6: error: reached end of file while parsing
    }
     ^
    2 errors
```

I don't have any ideas what going on here so please give detailed information and how to fix this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class static void main(string[] args)
```

Remove class

```
  public static void main(string[] args)
```

`class` is different from method. `main` method syntax doesn't contain `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Your main method needs to go inside a class: Java won't let you do things any other way.

Try:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this the basic structure for a simple program like this.

the class identifier, has to be on the declaration of the class.

```
public class Caculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably should be:

```
    public class JavaCode {

      public static void main(String[]args){

      }

    }
```

That should do it. ;)